# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}$ exist? [SOLVED]

Tags: calculus, limits

Does this limit exist, and if it does, what is it?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}$$

Was given the suggestion to use L'Hospital rule.

Comment: You can't use l'Hopital's rule unless you have a differentiable function; $(-1)^n$ doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0<\frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}<\frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+1)^n}{3^n}.$$
and you can prove, when $a>1$
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^3}{a^x}=0$$
by L'Hospital rule.
So $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+1)^n}{3^n}=0.$$
This implies (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

To facilitate analysis, define the functions:

$$F_-(n) \equiv n^3 \Big( \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{3} \Big)^n \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
F_+(n) \equiv n^3 \Big( \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{3} \Big)^n.$$

The function of interest in your problem is:

$$F(n) \equiv \frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n} = \begin{cases}
F_-(n) & & & \text{if } n \text{ is odd,} \\[6pt]
F_+(n) & & & \text{if } n \text{ is even.} \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

This function obeys the bounds:

$$F_-(n) \leqslant F(n) \leqslant F_+(n).$$

Now, it is quite easy to use L'Hôpital's rule to obtain $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_-(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} F_+(n) = 0$.  Thus, by application of the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} F(n) = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n:=\frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}$. Then $a_n >0$ for all $n$ and

$$ \lim \sup a_n^{1/n}=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{3}<1.$$

Hence the series $ \sum a_n$ is convergent. This gives

$$a_n \to 0.$$